# Running analysis code written in PostGIS from ArcGIS

Tags: postgis, arcgis-10.2, arcgis-server

I wrote some sql queries for PostGIS which does GIS processing, involving point/polygon feature and raster data for land covers.  I originally wrote it in ArcPy and arc tool box but performance was not good enough, moved to PostGIS.

Now I want to be able to use this tool from ArcGIS.  Is it doable, and where is description/documentation/example for doing it?  [I searched ESRI websites for PostGIS](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/databases/view-data-in-arcgis.htm), but they mention how to use data in database, and i couldn't easily find how do things like create schema, import data, populate table with new geometries/attributes etc.

Comment: Please ask only one question per Question.

Comment: You might have fared better in your search if you used the database name, and not just the spatial extension, though 10.2 was well short of the modern capabilities since 10.4.1 shipped. There's little reason for Esri to document how to use database tools to do database tasks. The sole bridge between database-centric operation and arcpy is `ArcSDESQLExecute`, though after 10.4 an enterprise geodatabase is no longer necessary to create snd populate tables without SQL.

Comment: Why do you want to use the tool from ArcGIS. Visualization? If the code runs better in Postgis than Arc (anything), almost guaranteed in my experience, why not look for other alternatives for you front end too. ArcGIS is just a very expensive, non-scalable, non-interoperable and massively old skool way of doing GIS. Just me 2c.

Comment: Thank you John + Vince for advises!   Yes, I think I am looking for tool for visualization of inputs/outputs and also graphical user interface allowing user to pick input by point/click.  I research alternative to ArcGIS as GUI tool, starting places like https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/13769/how-to-create-a-simple-front-end-for-a-postgis-database